# Retrieving Last Day of Event via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently attempting to use Google Apps Script to pull all-day events on a Google Calendar and export some data into Google Spreadsheets.

NOTE: the calendar ONLY has all-day events

The data I am trying to pull is:
- Title
- Start Date
- End Date

I am using the following in my apps script:

```
var mycal = "[Calendar ID/Address]";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("May 1, 2017 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("August 31, 2017 23:59:59 CST"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Start", "Event End"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4);
range.setValues(header);

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);
```

Unfortunately, the "getEndTime" doesn't give me the last day of the event, but rather the day after.  I'm sure this is by design, but does anyone have any advice as to how I'd pull in the ACTUAL last day of an event?

NOTE: I'm a complete novice with this, and apologies if the answer is quite easy!

Comment: It will give you the next day if its an all day event and therefore it is by design. You can probably reduce by one day yourself or use [getAllDayEndDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getalldayenddate).

Comment: @jackBrown - getAllDayEndDate() didn't seem to work.  However, what is the proper way to subtract 1 from the date given within google scripts.

Again, apologies if this question seems quite novice, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not able get the last day of the event from the calender. You can subtract one day from your date to get the final day of the calendar event. You can use following to subtract on day from your date

```
function sub1day(date){

 if (date == null)
   var dt = new Date()
 else
   dt = date

 Logger.log("Current date: "+ dt)
 //Method 1
 var prevDay = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()-1,dt.getHours(),dt.getMinutes(),dt.getSeconds())
 Logger.log(" Method 1, previous day: "+ prevDay)

 //Method 2
 var time = dt.getTime() // in ms
 var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000  //1 day in ms
 prevDay = new Date(time - oneDay)
 Logger.log("Method 2, previous day: "+ prevDay)

 return prevDay

}
```

Method 1, use a Date constructor to construct a new date from individual components of the current dt obejct. The previous day is determined by subtracting one from Date returned by `getDate()` function of a date object

Method 2, get the current date as time and subtract one day in milliseconds(ms). And create the new date from substracted time.

You can find more documentation on [Date object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: If the solution worked please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, so other know the question is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The end time of an all day event is midnight after the end, so you just need to subtract a minute. The following does that, the event end time is now 23:59, by using setMinute. (More information on [set date methods here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods_set.asp))

(This is useful if you want to later use it to check, e.g., which events are currently running, you don't want to subtract 24 hours.)

```
// add the following:
var eventEndTime = []; // new variable introduced which will give the intended end time.

eventEndTime[i] = events[i].getEndTime(); // sets eventEndTime to the normal event end time.
if (events[i].isAllDayEvent()) {
  eventEndTime[i].setMinutes(eventEndTime[i].getMinutes() - 1);  // if it is an all day event it redefines eventEndTime by subtracting  1 minute.
}

// then use this new variable instead of `events[i].getEndTime()` in `details` 
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(), eventEndTime[i]]]; // use the new variable instead of events[i].getEndTime()
```

(I'm also a novice, so let me know if there's something I could have done better in the code here, etc...)